# Bandwidth vs linewidth

Tags: optics, laser

Regarding to lasers sources, what is the difference between bandwidth and linewidth,  I know that a lot of people use linewidth when you have monochromatic source, but is there any difference between them, or is only the use?

Answer (score 3):

While there may be stricter definitions for each term, colloquially *bandwidth* usually refers to the band of frequencies or wavelengths a laser can output, while *linewidth* usually refers to the full-width at half-maximum (FWHM) of the emitted light in the optical spectrum. But, the linewidth may sometimes also be called bandwidth, usually not vice versa though.

So you might have a tunable laser with a bandwidth (other names could be *output range* or *tuning range*) of 200 nm with a FWHM linewidth of 5 MHz.

Here are two articles on RP Photonics that discuss these two terms:

- [RP Photonics - bandwidth](https://www.rp-photonics.com/bandwidth.html)
- [RP Photonics - linewidth](https://www.rp-photonics.com/linewidth.html)

Comment: And more generally, if we observe a band we speak of bandwidth, if we are after lines we speak of linewidth. Think of molecular vs atomic emissions, for instance.